# Java "Cannot find symbol" in Enterprise Architect API

Tags: java, compilation, enterprise

I'm trying to get a package-object (get by id) from the repository of Enterprise Architect (Sparx Systems) and get the package name.

Here's a code snippet:

```
org.sparx.Package oPackage = null;
oPackage = repo.GetPackageByID(Integer.parseInt(packageID));
String sName = oPackage.Name;
```

When I run my script, I get the following compilation error:

```
deleteExternalRef.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
               String sName = oPackage.Name;
                                      ^
 symbol:   variable Name
 location: variable oPackage of type Package
1 error
```

Am I doing something wrong in the Java code or am I using the EA-API in a wrong way? I can use methods of the Package class. Only when I try to use the variables, I get this error.

Comment: Cannot find symbol means you may not have imported that package or scope problem.Check what is in your case

Comment: They're still selling that? Don't try to generate code from EA.

Comment: First of all: I'm not trying to generate code from EA. I'm writing a script with the EA API to do something in EA.

Normally I've imported the correct package, because I'm able to use methods of the package class. The error only occurs when I try to access variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> String sName = oPackage.Name;

you should use Sparx EA JAVA API (eaapi.jar), and your line will be following:

```
String sName = oPackage.GetName();
```